# Java Help: Convert a String to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java

I have a string exactly as "[1,2,3,4,5]". Now I want to add  1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as normal elements inside a Arraylist. What is the best approach? One way can be to use String.split elements into a string array and then iterate and parse elements to Integer before adding to Arraylist but even in that case I don't know the exact regex to use in .Split function.

Comment: Splitting gets you 90% there.  The other 10% comes from dealing with the square brackets and then finding something that will accept an array and produce a `List`.  You may find something useful in the `Arrays` class.

Comment: Get rid of first and last characters (brackets) and split by `,`

Comment: You want it to be a `List<Integer>` right?  So you'll need to call `Integer.parseInt()` a few times in there.

Comment: P.S.:  There is a name for what you're trying to do.  Any time you extract structured information that is _encoded_ in a string, it's called "parsing" the string.  The code that does the job is called a "parser", and the rules that describe how the information is encoded are called "syntax rules" (or usually, just "syntax").

Answer (score 2):

This is a JSON string so you can use any JSON API to read it.

For example using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
String s = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
List<Integer> l = new ObjectMapper().reader(List.class).readValue(s);
```

Comment: It also looks a lot like the output of `ArrayList.toString()`, so JSON might be over-kill here.

Answer (score 1):

(the hard way)

First, remove the square brackets, then split the string, and finally parse each entry of the splitted array to an integer:

```
String s = "[1,2,3,4,5]";
String x = s.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""); // The regex you need to find "[\[\]], 
                                         // because you want to remove any square
                                         // brackets
String[] y = x.split(","); // Simply put the separator (a comma in this case)
int[] z = new int[y.length];
for(int i = 0; i < y.length; i++){
    z[i] = Integer.parseInt(y[i]);
}
```

If you want a list instead of an array, then:

```
ArrayList<Integer> z = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(string t : y) {
    z.add(Integer.parseInt(t));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String chain = "[1,2,3,4,5]";  //This is your String
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();  //This is the ArrayList where you want      to put the String

    String chainWithOutBrackets = chain.substring(1,chain.length()-1); //The String without brackets
    String[] array = chainWithOutBrackets.split(",");  //Split the previous String for separate by commas
    for(String s:array){  //Iterate over the previous array for put each element on the ArrayList like Integers
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(s)); 
    }
}
```